# Working on an Angular CLI Project Across 2 Computers with GitHub

Tags: angular, github, command-line-interface

I created a project using the Angular CLI and pushed it up to GitHub with the default .gitignore file.  Now I'd like to work on it on a different machine.  Since I didn't push the entire CLI, I can't just clone it.  I did install the CLI on the new device, but don't know how to update just the non-ignored files.

What I really want is to be able to regularly switch between the two machines while keeping the latest version on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have Pushed code on git hub with .gitignore.

Once you clone the code from repository.

You need to run np install to get updated dependency packages so your code will work with new clone

**Steps:**

1. Push Code to github repositery with gitignore
2. Clone code from repository on machine where you want to work
3. Run npm install
4. Run npm start

Answer (score 0):

The [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#usage) tool should be independent of the `ng new PROJECT-NAME` that you have created.

Only that new project should be in a Git repository.

On your second machine, once the Angular CLI is installed, all you need to do is clone that project and keep working in it.